# Proftpd directory listing error on Docker container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I have been using proftpd on Ubuntu inside a Docker container. It logs in successfully but failed to get directory listing.

**Here is the screenshot of Filezilla**

[image]

**And screenshot of Proftpd log file**

[image]

Any help?

Comment: @h_a86 : **Please add more details!** *(like your configuration file)*

Comment: and you container start up command

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the **proftpd** advertises the internal ip address 172.... so the client cannot connect to it.

You can solve this by setting (in the proftpd.conf)

```
MasqueradeAddress externalIP
```

or by running the conatiner using:

```
docker run --net=host  .....
```

This option uses the host ip network so the passive mode will work fine.

Comment: Using the `MasqueradeAddress` fixed the issue for me so I can continue to use a custom bridge network. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to expose configured passive ports (e.g. PassivePorts 60000 65534) on the running container to allow incoming connections

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the ftpd is having permissions problem changing the running user of some sort.
Try setting the ftpd to run as the user you are logging in with using dockers `USER userftp` (https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#user) in your Dockerfile.

Remember that you can make it listen on a port > 1024 and use `-p 21:2121` when starting the container to make it run on port 21 out to the world.

It would be helpful if you posted the Dockerfile and configuration you are using so we can test out this ourself.